# Is it possible to create a XLS excel file using Node.js with control over cell type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, npm

I see a lot of libraries out there that can export out to XLSX (excel > 2007) or CSV but not in XLS (I'm guessing because it's really old file format).

I found somewhere else that if you use

> fs.createOutputStream("filename.xls")

and write into that writestream, you can def create your own XLS file but they all come out as "General" under cell type. I need one of the cell types to be "Number" or "Text" because it's a string that signifies a ID number like "244829482042". When it's left as "General", it displays instead as "2.4 E11"

Is it possible to use createOutputStream and create a XLS file with format control over cell type? Or is there any library that does this or can help accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...and write into that writestream, you can def create your own XLS file

This is incorrect. You're actually writing a CSV file - just that the filename just-so-happens to incorrectly have `.xls` as the extension, but Excel is just being helpful and lets you open the file anyway, but it knows its a CSV file.

I don't believe it is currently possible to write a correct binary XLS file in Node.js as I'm not aware of any file-format libraries for Node or JavaScript.

Writing XLSX files is considerably easier as it is a well-documented XML file format (actually, multiple XML files, contained within a zip archive - if you rename an `.xlsx` file to `.zip` you can look inside them).

Comment: do you know any libraries that can actually change the number format of a cell from "General" to "Number" correctly? It seems unexpectedly difficult to find, thank u

Answer (score 0):

A quick internet search gives:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/msexcel-builder

Comment: This library only generates Office Open XML (OOXML) (`.xlsx`) files, not the Office 97-2003 binary `.xls` files.

Comment: Are you sure? It says right in info...create ms office 2007 files

Comment: "Office 2007" uses OOXML files.

Comment: Ahhhh. Didn't see the distinction